# Python's random module is not importing

Tags: python, random, import

I am having problems importing Python's random module using Eclipse. It creates a red line under `random` when I do:

```
import random
```

I think I may have accidentally deleted it, and if so, how can I get it back? I tried copying and pasting the source from the Python documents, but it won't compile.

Comment: What error message do you get when you run "import random"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try importing `random` in a Python shell. If this does not work, then reinstall Python.

If only Pydev is complaining about `random` being missing, then you should try rebuilding Pydev's module paths in the preferences.

Comment: How do you rebuild Pydev's module paths? Thanks! I am having the same problem as David.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have deleted or moved the file, in which case it is simply easier to re-download python from the python website: https://www.python.org/downloads/